# No module named "tflib"

Tags: python, module

On [this GitHub page](https://github.com/igul222/improved_wgan_training) of "Improved WGAN Training", particularly in their [Python-Cifar-file](https://github.com/igul222/improved_wgan_training/blob/master/gan_cifar.py/), the authors use the Python-module `tflib`. I installed it via pip (`pip install tflib`), but when I import it, I still get the error message `No module named tflib`.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tflib/) is an unknown package.

If you look closely in the github repository, you will find that the `tflib` is actually a custom [module](https://github.com/igul222/improved_wgan_training/tree/master/tflib) made by the author and provided in the [same repository](https://github.com/igul222/improved_wgan_training). Cloning the full repository will help resolve the issue

Comment: Just to make sure: I first intall tensorflow and then tflib? :)

Comment: @Imahn I have edited the answer. It is actually provided in the repository. Let me know if this resolves

Comment: I'm currently cloning the repo. :)

Comment: I am doing this on the cloud (AWS). Is it safe to clone a repo into the terminal, because I have to enter my GitHub passwd?

Comment: Yes, it is safe. If you don't wish to enter github password, you can clone via [https](https://github.com/igul222/improved_wgan_training.git) which will not ask for password.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229284/discussion-between-smartymcfly-and-imahn).